# iOS ImageView not filling screen and Button not on the bottom of screen

Tags: ios, swift, swift2

I'm new to iOS. I'm trying to achieve this layout in the app. I placed an ImageView and Button like that on the StoryBoard but when I run the app, the ImageView doesnt fill the screen and the Button is not in the bottom. How do I accomplish this?

[image]

Comment: Did you apply auto layout constraints ?

Answer (score 1):

You can watch [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Gl6DibzPYa4) video , this is the best for me about auto layouts.

And the easiest way is Add Missing Constraints [click here!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x0qOW.png)

Answer (score 0):

Set your UIImageView to scale to feel in atribute inspector and make sure about your autosizing should be like [this](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B5I4WIvp39a1eGZUSzNzc0puZm8).

Answer (score 0):

You have to set constraint in your InterfaceBuilder.

More Info here:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/WorkingwithConstraintsinInterfaceBuidler.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010853-CH10-SW1